# Redirecting files types on a sub hosted domain using htaccess is including folder name in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I don't do much with htaccess files and I found a little jem here I thought would do all I needed what I need to do is redirect every request for filename.htm to filename.php. What I tried is this

```
    `RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.htm$ $1.php
```

It redirects how ever it will include the sub domain folder name.

example: http://my-domain.com/www.my-domain.com//filename.php
www.my-domain.com is the name of the folder containing the site.
What has worked in the past has been

```
    `Redirect 301 /www.my-domain.com/filename.htm http://my-domain.com/filename.php
```

But I would have to have an entry for every page any help would be greatly appreciated ThankYou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using rewrite like this instead.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.htm$ http://www.example.com/$1.php [R=301,L]
```